# use boolean condition as a bit parameter in function

Tags: sql, parameters, user-defined-functions

I have a scalar function in sql with a bit parameter that cannot be null. I need to use a boolean condition instead of a bit variable in a select statement, something like:

```
select 
    dbo.myFuncyion(t1.field is null)
from 
    myTable t1
```

But this is not allowed in sql. 
I've used something like `isnull(select 1 where t1.field is null,0)` but I wonder if there is a faster way (this function will be called for more than 1 million of rows.

Regards

Comment: Can you not use something like `CASE WHEN t1.field IS NULL THEN dbo.myFunction(1) ELSE dbo.myFunction(0) END`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `CASE WHEN`:

```
select 
    dbo.myFuncyion(CASE WHEN t1.field is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from 
    myTable t1
```

Comment: is this the fastest way?

Comment: @BudaGavril : Not sure if fastest but definitely most portable. For example some engines support IIF(condition, true-result, false-result) but at the end it's translated probably to the same runtime code. In MySQL you can probably pass the result of expression `t1.field IS NULL` directly as an argument, this could be probably faster.

Comment: IIF is not available in sql server 2008

Comment: @BudaGavril - Then you might want to tag your question as SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statement to achive the samething:

```
    select 
    dbo.myFuncyion(CASE WHEN (t1.field IS NULL OR t1.field = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
from 
    myTable t1
```